# elasticsearch range filter for array field

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, range

I have a field containing an array of integers eg:

```
_source: {
  ...
  prices: [
    20001,
    30001
  ]
}
```

I'd like to filter the results such that prices contains at least one of a list of values which are between  eg:
`[20002,30000] #` would not return the above document because no value is between 20002 and 30000
but `[10000,20002]` would return above document because 20001 in the prices field of above document is between 10000 and 20002

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elasticsearch always considers that a field can contain a list of values so, a [range filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html) should work. If any of the values matches the range it will be filtered in.

You can use that filter as part of a [filtered query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "prices": {
            "gte": 10000,
            "lte": 20002
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, filtered query is deprecated in 2.0, so, if you are using 2.0 you can better use a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with a filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}   
      },  
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "prices": {
            "gte": 10000,
            "lte": 20002
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I'm using a filter in my examples because you asked for a filter :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer that correctly solve my question.

Comment: Done! It's the first time for me to ask questions here :)

Comment: I made the mistake of converting my integers to strings..... Best to leave them the way they are