# How can I save a Python list in an Elasticsearch index and perform searches within it?

Tags: python, list, elasticsearch

I have a Python list containing the start time in milliseconds of all scenes from a video, structured like this: [0, 1120, 670, ... 123098]. My objective is to store these lists in each document within the 'videos' index. Later, I will require retrieving a portion of the list for scenes between 'start_time' and 'end_time'. I aim to avoid using json.dumps to save a list as a string.

**Update:**

I am able to create a property and update it like this:

```
PUT /search-clipmaker_video/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
      "scenes_start_duration_ms": { 
        "type": "integer",
        "index":false
      }
    }

}
```

```
POST /search-clipmaker_video/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "video_id": "kjkjkjkkj"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.scenes_start_duration_ms=params.new_values",
    "params": {
      "new_values": [[0,1000], [1022,2020], [5670,2560]]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I wonder, if `a(i) < a(i+1)` always holds true, can I request to retrieve a subset of the array, for example, `[[a1,b1],...,[ai,bi]]` where `a1 > 1000` and `ai < 6000`? Or must I fetch the entire array and perform the search on the client side?

Comment: pls see if this answer using range query works for you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460549/elasticsearch-range-filter-for-array-field